# memory-optimized SQL Server tables - how can I ensure a table seek?

Tags: sql-server, performance, t-sql, memory-optimized-tables

I've been having some trouble getting a single-column "varchar(5)" field to reliably use a table seek instead of a table scan.  The production table in this case contains 25 million rows.  As impressive as it is to scan 25 million rows in 35 seconds, the query should run much faster.

Here's a partial table descriptions

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Summaries_MO]
(
    [SummaryId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [zipcode] [char](5) COLLATE Latin1_General_100_BIN2 NOT NULL,
    [Golf] [bit] NULL,
    [Homeowner] [bit] NULL,
    [IncomeCode] [char](1) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
    [Pets] [bit] NULL,

CONSTRAINT [Summaries_MO_primaryKey] PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED HASH 
(
    [SummaryId]
)WITH ( BUCKET_COUNT = 33554432),
INDEX [ixZIP] NONCLUSTERED 
(
    [zipcode] ASC
)
)WITH ( MEMORY_OPTIMIZED = ON , DURABILITY = SCHEMA_AND_DATA )
```

Typically, this table is accessed with a query that includes:

```
SELECT ...
            FROM SummaryTable

            WHERE ixZIP IN (SELECT ZipCode FROM @ZipCodesForMO)
```

This query insists on using a table scan.  I've tried WITH (FORCESEEK) for example, but that just makes the query fail.

As I've investigated this issue I also tried:

```
SELECT * FROM Summaries WHERE ZipCode IN ('xxxxx', 'xxxxx', 'xxxxx')
```

When I run this query with 64 or fewer (actual, valid) ZIP codes, the query uses a table seek.

But when I give it 65 or more ZIP codes it uses a table scan.

To summarize, the production query always uses a table scan, and when I specify 65 or more ZIP codes the query also uses a table scan.

Frankly, I'm wondering if the data type of the indexed column (Latin1_General_100_BIN2 NOT NULL) is somehow the problem.  I'll likely try converting the ZIP codes to an integer to see what happens.

But I'd rather know what's going on than simply try things randomly.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit long for a comment.

First, try rewriting as a `join`:

```
SELECT st.*
FROM SummaryTable st JOIN
     @ZipCodesForMO z
     ON st.ixZIP = z.ZipCode;
```

The reason for doing this is that `JOIN`s have more opportunities for optimization than `IN`.

I think the reason why SQL Server is preferring the full table scan is because each index seek needs to be followed by a page seek to fetch the rest of the columns in the table.  This doubles the amount of work.  You have narrow records, so even 25 million rows might fit on 30k or so pages.

I think a cutoff of 64 is too small.  But a list of 10,000 zip codes would require reading about 10,000 or so pages.  With an index seek, would -- in a very rough way -- double the effort.  So, a scan of the table might reasonably have similar or better performance (sequential scans are significantly optimized over random scans).

Answer (score 0):

Minimize size:
Use SmallInt for zipcode
Consider TinyInt for IncomeCode

Use a #temp for ZipCodesForMO with a PK
And a join

```
SELECT ...
FROM SummaryTable
JOIN #zipCodesForMOWHERE 
     on SummaryTable.zipcode = #zipCodesForMOWHERE.ZipCode
```